# AngularJS: Dynamically apply has-error to input fields

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, validation

I have html that is dynamically generated from JSON and I would like to implement some validation logic.

To clarify, here is an example:

```
<div  ng-switch on="field.type" ng-hide="{{ field.hide }}">
<div ng-switch-when="input" class= "col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error': reqField(field.name, entity[field.name]) }">
    <input
        ng-model="entity[field.name]" id="{{field.name}}" class="form-control" 
        type="text" ng-style="setStyle(field.style)" ng-change="{{field.change}}" />
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
    {
    "title": "Json Title",
    "id": "j_id",
    "groupfields": [
        {
            "name": "jsonname",
            "title": "JSON Title",
            "type": "jsonselect",
            "namevalue": "jsonvalue",
            "combo": "jsondropdown",
            "change" : "jsonChanged()"
        },
        {
            "name": "jsonEmail",
            "title": "JSON Email Address",
            "type": "display"
        },
        {
            "name": "jsonPhone",
            "title": "JSON Phone Number",
            "type": "display"
        }
    ]
},  {
    "title": "Json Title",
    "id": "j_id",
    "groupfields": [
        {
            "name": "jsonname",
            "title": "JSON Title",
            "type": "jsonselect",
            "namevalue": "jsonvalue",
            "combo": "jsondropdown",
            "change" : "jsonChanged()"
        },
        {
            "name": "jsonEmail",
            "title": "JSON Email Address",
            "type": "display"
        },
        {
            "name": "jsonPhone",
            "title": "JSON Phone Number",
            "type": "display"
        }
    ]
},
```

---

```
if (entityName) {
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
```

---

So for clarification, ex: 'field.type' in the ng-switch on is the "type" in the JSON - and we can determine which html div to display the content based on different JSON keys/values.

This implies that one html div could potentially be used to generate hundreds of input fields so this needs to be dynamic.

I would like to add validation for when a required field is empty. At the moment, I've tried adding the `ng-class="{has-error':   }` which points to my function reqField. However, because this function is getting fired for EVERY field with "type": jsonselect, this function is checking whether or not the field is empty - which is really inefficient in terms of speed and usability (super laggy).

The javascript you see above is more or less the logic that the function `reqField()` does in order to check whether or not the field is empty (very inefficient since we're checking hundreds).

What I would like to use is something along the lines of `ng-required={{field.required}}` and make a new key/value in the JSON to determine whether or not I want this field to be a required field (sort like this):

```
 {
"title": "Json Title",
"id": "j_id",
"groupfields": [
    {
        "name": "jsonname",
        "title": "JSON Title",
        "type": "jsonselect",
        "namevalue": "jsonvalue",
        "combo": "jsondropdown",
        "change" : "jsonChanged()"
    },
    {
        "name": "jsonEmail",
        "title": "JSON Email Address",
        "type": "display",
        "required": true
    },
    {
        "name": "jsonPhone",
        "title": "JSON Phone Number",
        "type": "display",
        "required": true
    }
]
},
```

~ and somehow pass that information to the `ng-class="{has-error':   }` so that we can highlight - or do whatever we want once we know the field has been filled in/or is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form validation is built in to AngularJS. The `ng-required` directive will add error state to the form object, so that you can set up your `ng-class` like so:

```
<div ng-switch-when="input" class= "col-md-6" ng-class="{'has-error': myForm[field.name].$error.required }">
```

Your form and input **must have** `name` **attributes** for this to work:

```
<form name="myForm">
...
  <input name="{{field.name}}" ng-required="field.required">
```